# Setting the order of a list based on a corresponding list with matching values

Tags: python

I have 2 lists:

> a = [orange,apple,peach,watermelon,gum]
>
> b = [3,4,1,2,0]

In this case, I want to take the values stored in each index in list `b` and then move the elements that correspond to each element in list `a` in accordance to that value.

To give a clearer example, with the above code if re-ordered the result would be:

> a = [gum,peach,watermelon,orange,apple]

Since the first item in list b is `3` I need to move the corresponding first value in list `a` (in this case `oranges`) to that index position of the list, so it  has now moved to  index position 3 after being re-ordered.

Since `0` is the last element of list `b` it corresponds to the last element in list `a` (in this case `gum`), so the last element of list `a` should be moved to index position 0, as above.

We can assume that list b will be the same length as list a and that the index values will correspond to the ones in list a.

Comment: `[v for _, v in sorted(zip(b, a))]`

Comment: Thank you! I actually saw that question first and tried it but had the variables passed wrong (a, b) instead which is why it wasn't working.